# Kotlin: Maps comparison throws Fail even if Maps are equal

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to compare 2 Maps, both are filled with identical Strings (just for training).
When I try to compare them I got `false` returned through `map.equals(map2)`

But if I do the same and add `.toString()` to the `comparison` it returns `true`. `map.toString().equals(map2.toString())`

How's that? What am I doing wrong?

Also happens the same with `Kluent library` and its `shouldEqual` method. 
I also tried to get `values` of that `maps` into `arrays` and tried to compare that `arrays` but it still returns `false`.

Also, when I print all items from each map I see the same 3 Strings but comparison returns `fail`.

Here's the code:

```
class MapsTesting {


    class Items(name1: String, amount1: String, price1: String) {
        var name: String = name1
        var amount: String = amount1
        var price: String = price1

        override fun toString(): String {
            return "name:$name,amount:$amount,price:$price \n"
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun mapTest() {

        val mapOfItems: MutableMap<String, Items> = mutableMapOf()
        mapOfItems["Materials"] = Items("STEP 1", "STEP 2", "View All Stones")

        val mapOfItems2: MutableMap<String, Items> = mutableMapOf()
        mapOfItems2["Materials"] = Items("STEP 1", "STEP 2", "View All Stones")

        mapOfItems.forEach { t, u ->
            println("map key:$t,map value:${u.toString()}")
        }

        mapOfItems2.forEach { t, u ->
            println("map key:$t,map value:${u.toString()}")
        }

        val comparison : Boolean = mapOfItems.toString().equals(mapOfItems2.toString())
        //this returns true
        val comparison2 : Boolean = mapOfItems.equals(mapOfItems2)
         //this returns false
        println(comparison)
        println(comparison2)


        val map1 = mapOfItems.toString()
        val map2 = mapOfItems2.toString()
        //this returns true 
        //if I delete toString() it will return false
        map1 shouldEqual  map2
    }
}
```

Here's the error I got:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.LinkedHashMap<{Materials=name:STEP 1,amount:STEP 2,price:View All Stones 
}> but was: java.util.LinkedHashMap<{Materials=name:STEP 1,amount:STEP 2,price:View All Stones 
}>
```

Comment: The types are different. That alone probably causes it to fail. The string representations would be equal if toString ditches any class indicators and just shows the strings.

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of the classes? Also, your map names in the first code block you posted are mixed up somehow.

Comment: @Carcigenicate @zsmb13 edited post with new details. Also, I deleted 2nd class `Items2` but it still the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When comparing two maps with the `equals` method, the standard implementation compares all keys and values also using the `equals` method.

Your `Items` class uses the standard `equals` implementation (two reference values are equal if and only if they refer to the same object). But you clearly have two different instances of the in different maps.

You either have to override the `Items#equals` method or mark the `Items` class as a `data class`:

```
data class Items(var name1: String, var amount1: String, var price1: String)
```

Kotlin will generate correct `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

After this the map comparison will work fine.

Comment: > When comparing two maps with the equals method, the standard implementation compares all keys and values also using the equals method.

This is true.  However, be aware that neither the Map nor the MutableMap interfaces require this.